# If parent class has X then do this, else this

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I want .fourth added to the fourth .service-list when its inside:

```
 <section class="sixteen">
```

When it's any other class I want to add .third to the third .service-list.

e.g

```
 if ($("section").hasClass("sixteen")) {

     $('div.service-list').filter(function(index){
     return (index%4 == 3);
     }).addClass('fourth');

 } else {

     $('div.service-list').filter(function(index){
     return (index%3 == 2);
     }).addClass('third');
 }
```

However this seems to find ANY .sixteen on the page. I just want it to check the parent of the .service-list's.

At the moment is finds another .sixteen down the page and adds .fourth when I need .third because it's inside a smaller grid.

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xu3Yq/

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. It sounds like you have two sections with class `sixteen`. One of them needs `fourth` added and one of them needs `third` added because it is smaller. How are you supposed to differentiate between the two?

Comment: Sorry mrtsherman, it was a bit hard to explain. I need the .service-list divs inside a larger column (sixteen) to have every 4th div to have a class attached. When it's not the large column it needs third attached.

The problem I was having is that if another sixteen class is somewhere on the page (regardless of whether .service-list was in it) fourth was being appended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$('section')​​​​​​​.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('sixteen')) {
        $this.find('div.service-list:eq(3)').addClass('fourth');
    } else {
        $this.find('div.service-list:eq(2)').addClass('third');
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mzwqD/